# C++: thread sync

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, mutex, condition-variable

I am trying to synchronize two thread (working on the same C++ map) using the Boost library. I must tell that I am not an expert in C++ and I find the boost documentation quite hard to understand.

What I want to achieve, is something like this:

```
#Thread 1
get access to the map
put in something
release access 

#Thread 2
wait until map is empty
when it's not empty anymore, wake up and gain access
perform operations on one entry of the map
leave access to somebody else
```

I tried to use Mutex and condition_variables, but the code was not working properly. In specific, when thread2 was waking up (after waiting the cond. variable), it was not gaining directly access to the map, but there was somebody else that got access and emptied the map. Therefore, I got segmentation fault, because I was expecting the map to be full while it was empty when I accessed it.

In addition, I would like to understand the difference between something like `mymutex.lock()` and invokations like `boost::mutex::scoped_lock scopedLock(mutex_)`;
 or `unique_lock`.

Thanks for teaching :)

EDIT: here I tried to extract the relevant parts of my code. Since I did not understand very well how sync works, it may not make much sense...

```
//COMMON PART
boost::mutex mutex1;
boost::mutex mutex2;
boost::condition_variable cond;
boost::mutex::scoped_lock mutex2lock(mutex2);

//THREAD 1
...
if(someCondition){
    mutex1.lock();
    map[id]=message;
    cond.notify_one();
    mutex1.unlock();
}
...


//THREAD 2
...
cond.wait(mutex2lock);
mutex.lock();
//Perform operation on map[id]
doSomething(map[id]));
mutex.unlock();
...
```

Comment: You should add some code on what the actual threads are doing. It is hard to debug *when thread2 was waking up it was not gaining direct access to the map*... Your description seems to indicate that there is a single producer and a single consumer, which would not explain *somebody else that emptied the map*. Are there only 2 threads? are they really sharing the map?

Comment: yes, they are really sharing the map, which is a kind of container. Both threads can put/take away stuff. What is happening sometimes is that thread1 gains access two times one after another. The first time it puts there something. In the meanwhile thread2 wakes up because it saw the notify. BUT, before thread2 goes on, thread1 is executed again and this time it takes the entry out of the map. Sorry for being so messy in explaining, I hope it's clear enough :P

Comment: Why is thread1 **ever** taking something out of the map?? That's just begging for trouble. Also, that's something that you should really have included in the example code.

Comment: Thread1 is a receiving function. If I receive a message that is not in the map, I put it in. If I receive the message and its already in the map, I move it out of the map (somewhere else). In synthesis, what I want to achieve is that when thread2 resumes after wait() it really has exclusive access on that map. I must be sure that thread2 sees the entry that was put by thread1. Hope I am clear enough :) Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock mutex2lock(mutex2);
```

This should, if I understand correctly, but a big lock on mutex2 that'll last the length of your Mutex.

Likely you want that lock within the context of the second thread, but I don't much understand why condition_variable wants it.

In fact, it seems that condition_variable itself is a bit wrong for what you are doing, reading the documentation:

> Atomically call lock.unlock() and blocks the current thread. The thread will unblock when notified by a call to this->notify_one() or this->notify_all(), or **spuriously**

That description seems to me that it can just unlock when it feels it can run (likely based on time) It seems you would likely need to check to see if you the list is valid, and if not, call wait again, if you plan to use condition_variable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The problem is exactly as you described it. Thread2 waits for the map to be "valid" (not empty). When it is valid, it must go on being sure that there is something in the map.

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, I would like to
>   understand the difference between
>   something like mymutex.lock() and
>   invokations like
>   boost::mutex::scoped_lock
>   scopedLock(mutex_); or unique_lock.

Google for "c++ RAII":

With `mymutex.lock()` you are "manually" locking the mutex. (And later have to unlock it "manually".)

scoped_lock is a helper class that does locking - and automatic unlocking at end of its scope - for you.